# order of packages: svg and tocloft

Tags: tocloft, svg

The following MWE illustrate the issue:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[clean,pdf]{svg}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\includesvg[width=\textwidth{}]{legacy-ip-only}
\end{document}
```

It will not compile, because the following message is shown:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \c@lofdepth already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.607   \newcounter{lofdepth}
                             \setcounter{lofdepth}{1}
?
```

If `tocloft` will be included before `svg` the MWE compiles without any error. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally, `svg` requires `subfig`:

```
\@ifpackageloaded{subfig}{}{\RequirePackage{subfig}}%
```

And `subfig` already defines the `lofdepth` counter.

When you load `tocloft` without the `subfigure` option, the package creates the `lofdepth` counter:

```
\if@cftsubfigopt\else
  \newcounter{lofdepth}\setcounter{lofdepth}{1}
  \newcounter{lotdepth}\setcounter{lotdepth}{1}
\fi
```

and this obviously triggers the error.

You can prevent this either changing the order in which you load the packages beacause `subfig` internally checks if the counter has been previously defined and, in that case, it doesn't define it:

```
\def\@newsubfloat[#1]#2{%
  \@ifundefined{c@sub#2}{%
    \newcounter{sub#2}[#2]
    \newcounter{sub#2@save}%
    \@namedef{sub#2name}{}%
    \@namedef{p@sub#2}{\@nameuse{the#2}}%
    \@namedef{thesub#2}{\alph{sub#2}}%
    \@namedef{ext@sub#2}{\@nameuse{ext@#2}}%
    \@namedef{l@sub#2}{%
        \@dottedxxxline{#2}%
            {\@nameuse{ext@sub#2}}{2}{\sf@indent}{\sf@numwidth}}%
    \@ifundefined{c@\@nameuse{ext@#2}depth}{%
      \expandafter\newcounter\expandafter{\@nameuse{ext@#2}depth}%
      \expandafter\addtocounter\expandafter{\@nameuse{ext@#2}depth}\@ne}{}%
    \@namedef{KV@caption@\@nameuse{ext@#2}depth@default\expandafter}%
        \expandafter{\csname KV@caption@\@nameuse{ext@#2}depth\endcsname{2}}%
    \@namedef{KV@caption@\@nameuse{ext@#2}depth}##1{%
        \setcounter{\@nameuse{ext@#2}depth}{##1}}%
    \edef\sf@counterlist{%
      \@ifundefined{sf@counterlist}{}%
        {\sf@counterlist,}sub#2}%
    \captionsetup[sub#2]{#1}%
  }{%
    \PackageWarning{subfig}{%
        The sub#2\space type is already defined.}%
  }}
```

Another way to prevent the error is using the `subfigure` option for `tocloft`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[clean,pdf]{svg}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\includesvg[width=\textwidth{}]{legacy-ip-only}
\end{document}
```